# Custom Tikz arrowhead with bar before triangle 45

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How do I make a custom arrowhead in Tikz having a perpendicular bar before a triangle 45?  I would also like to adapt this solution to a bar before a square, open square, etc.

For example, imagine arrow coming from (0,0) to (10,0), then the arrowhead would be a filled triangle roughly (9,1) -- (10, 0) -- (9, -1).  I want to add a bar, which is a filled rectangle roughly (8.5,1) -- (8.6, 1) -- (8.6, -1) -- (8.5, -1).

I guess I can use `pgfdeclarearrow` to declar a bar somehow and then `pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*` to combine it with existing arrows?

Comment: Could you draw a picture using MS paint or something?

Comment: I think you may want to have a look to [Can I combine arrow tips in TikZ/pgf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9416/13304)

Comment: @JohnKormylo: edited.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Thanks, I missed that question, so I'm now closer to a solution.

Comment: How about defining `|>` to mean `Triangle[open]` using `\tikzset`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With the `arrows.meta` library in `pgf` 3.0 (released December 2013), combining arrow heads is pretty simple and can be done in advance or in-line:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  tipA/.tip={Bar[sep]Triangle[open,angle=45:4pt]},
  tipB/.tip={Bar[sep]Square[open]}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-tipA] (0,0)  -- +(1,0);
\draw [-tipB] (0,.5) -- +(1,0);
% in-line
\draw [-{Bar[sep]Triangle[angle=45:4pt]}] (0,1)   -- +(1,0);
\draw [-{Bar[sep]Square[]}]   (0,1.5) -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for [Thomas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/42660/Thomas):

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  tipA/.tip={Bar[sep]Triangle[open,angle=45:4pt]},
  tipB/.tip={Bar[sep]Square[open]},
  legs/.tip={Straight Barb[reversed]},
  long legs/.tip={Straight Barb[reversed,angle=30:4pt]},
  hat/.tip={Bracket[reversed,sep=-1pt]Rectangle[]},
  arms/.tip={Bar[sep]},
  head/.tip={Circle[]},
  skirt/.tip={Triangle[reversed]},
  arms down/.tip={Straight Barb[angle=35:4pt]},
  long hair/.tip={Arc Barb[length=9pt,width=6pt,sep=-9pt]Arc Barb[length=9pt,width=5pt,sep=-9pt]Arc Barb[length=9pt,width=7pt]}
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\draw [legs-tipA] (0,0)  -- +(0,1);
\draw [legs-tipB] (1,0) -- +(0,1);
% in-line
\draw [legs-{Bar[sep]Triangle[angle=45:4pt]}] 
  (2,0)   -- +(0,1);
\draw [legs-{Bar[sep]Square[]}]   
  (3,0) -- +(0,1);
\draw [legs-{arms[]head[sep=-1pt]hat[]}]   
  (4,0) -- +(0,1);
\draw [{long legs[]skirt[sep=-2pt]}-{arms down[]head[sep=-8.5pt]long hair[]}]   
  (5,0) -- +(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [installation of `arrows.meta`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63982/512)

Comment: if you bend your head to the right, you will see a bunch of tall people with short arms.

Comment: @Thomas and possibly with a hat.

Comment: Your edit is awesome !

Comment: Got it working, thank you!!  Your people example is not only cute, but it's very instructive.